# using guided access in iPhone 6 programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios6, guided-access

Until now asper my knowledge it was not possible to restrict the app from exiting. User could press the home button and app will exit. Then came multitasking and when we press home button app would go in background, but on long press user can still close the app.

I am working on developing anti-theft kind of application and needed to lock the phone programatically, but seems that it is not possible.

Also another problem was if user exits app then there is no way it will get notifications from the web. After some research I found the we can restrict the application from being exited using [GUIDED ACCESS](http://www.assistiveware.com/support/faq/page/136) facility provided by iPhone6.

But all the links that I found states the procedure to do it from settings menu of iPhone.
I wanted to know if there is any way to do it programmatically or at least display relevent iphone settings screen directly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to restrict your app from exiting or allowing it to lock the iPhone programatically.

This is FAR beyond the scope and bounds of security for your app to infect the system this way.

As for **Guided Access** it is a feature provided in iOS6 allowing parents to use their device with their kids and prevent accidental app exits or unintentional taps outside a certain bounds. It also has availability in a kiosk mode for small businesses using iPads as public information access points that want the iPad locked to an app or webpage. It is not a public API allowing your app to turn such blocks on. This again is for the security of the device.

Comment: Is there no way I can atleast mimic this functionality? as I mentioned, I am working on kind of anti-theft application. So if the user exits application the whole purpose is defeated.

I have also searched if there is any way that I can lock the device remotely. Heard something about MDM, but not able to find much on this. 

If you have any other idea on this I would really appreciate if you can share them :)

Comment: It is entirely impossible to keep the app from exiting or to lock the device remotely. These are extremely sensitive requests that are the first things malware would look to exploit. The best you can do is set your app to never let the screen go to sleep, then the user can manually turn on Guided Access to keep your app open. They can also use the Free Find My iPhone service from Apple to remotely lock it.